grep the string and return the line with the highest value if no ties
Given the strings I have that are based on ASVs (like keys) from a different file, I want to return the ASV matches that have the highest value. However, there are sometimes ties which can be a problem so instead I want to return a message.
I am able to return the line with the highest value after sorting, but I don't know how to account for ties properly.
Here is a snippet of my file called file.txt:
ASV,Kingdom,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Species,Hits
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,Chloroflexota,Anaerolineae,???,???,???,uncultured Anaerolineae,2
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,Chloroflexota,???,???,???,???,uncultured Chloroflexota,1
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,unidentified marine,1
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,Chloroflexota,Chloroflexia,Chloroflexales,Chloroflexaceae,Chloroflexus,uncultured Chloroflexus,1
74627d6dc445e8b5f46a787cf81c4294,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Legionellales,Legionellaceae,???,uncultured Legionellaceae,2
74627d6dc445e8b5f46a787cf81c4294,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5
74627d6dc445e8b5f46a787cf81c4294,Bacteria,Pseudomonadota,Gammaproteobacteria,Legionellales,Legionellaceae,Legionella,Legionella sp.,3
55b1bec5f8dbe1b58007aee7ede9bae3,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma utsteinense,2
55b1bec5f8dbe1b58007aee7ede9bae3,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,2
55b1bec5f8dbe1b58007aee7ede9bae3,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma sp.,2
55b1bec5f8dbe1b58007aee7ede9bae3,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma rigui,6
8964b7d833654ceedbdb6f6f25fb7d6a,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,8
8964b7d833654ceedbdb6f6f25fb7d6a,Bacteria,Bacillota,Tissierellia,Tissierellales,Peptoniphilaceae,Finegoldia,Finegoldia magna,1
8964b7d833654ceedbdb6f6f25fb7d6a,???,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured organism,1
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Sphingobacteriia,Sphingobacteriales,???,???,uncultured Cytophagales,2
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma jeollabukense,2
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma migulaei,2
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma sp.,1

As an example, searching for the ASV 29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7 and returning the match with the highest value (the very last column) is easy:
Code:
> grep 29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7 file.txt | sort -t, -nr -k9 | head -n1

# Output
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5

But if I am searching an ASV such as 9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9, I would need it to somehow return or know that three lines can be returned (3 of them have the value 2) and instead output a message:
Ideal output:
  > grep 9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9 file.txt | does something

  # Output
  CHECK: There are 3 lines tied for top.


Learn a little about awk.

You say "based on ASVs (like keys) from a different file" but you don't show such a file in your question which is why you're getting solutions that call awk one ASV at a time instead of a solution that reads all the ASVs and processes all of them together in a single call to awk, which would be a much faster (and probably more robust) approach.

... and if you do want to perform the ASV lookups based on a list of ASVs/keys in another file then consider asking a new question; do not rewrite, or extend, this question otherwise you negate all of the answers you've received so far; between your last question and this question you should have everything you need for a solution to perform a mass lookup based on a file of ASVs/keys - and if you have problems with such a solution then include your coding attempts in the new question

I would opt for an awk solution:

eliminates need for sorting
eliminates overhead of subshells
easy to add desired logic

One awk idea:
awk -F, -v asv="29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7" '
$1 == asv { if ($NF >= max_val) {
               if ($NF > max_val) {
                  delete matches
                  cnt = 0
                  max_val = $NF
               }
               matches[++cnt] = $0
            }
          }
END       { if (cnt == 0)
               print "WARNING: No lines found."
            else 
            if (cnt==1)
               print matches[cnt]
            else
               printf "CHECK: There are %s lines tied for top [max value = %s].\n", cnt, max_val
          }
' file.txt

For asv="123" this generates:
WARNING: No lines found.

For asv="29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7" this generates:
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5

For asv="9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9" this generates:
CHECK: There are 3 lines tied for top [max value = 2].

Wrapping this in a bash function:
max_asv() {
awk -F, -v asv="$1" '
$1 == asv { if ($NF >= max_val) {
               if ($NF > max_val) {
                  delete matches
                  cnt = 0
                  max_val = $NF
               }
               matches[++cnt] = $0
            }
          }
END       { if (cnt == 0)
               print "WARNING: No lines found."
            else 
            if (cnt==1)
               print matches[cnt]
            else
               printf "CHECK: There are %s lines tied for top [max value = %s].\n", cnt, max_val
          }
' "$2"
}

Taking the function for a test drive:
$ max_asv 123 file.txt
WARNING: No lines found.

$ max_asv 29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7 file.txt
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5

$ max_asv 9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9 file.txt
CHECK: There are 3 lines tied for top [max value = 2].


Oh yea this worked great! Can you explain a little why we need that last box of [%s] in the last comment where we are returning the "CHECK" phrase?

@KatherineChau updated to display as [max value = 2]; if you don't want to print the max value then replace the line with printf "CHECK: There are %s lines tied for top.\n", cnt

@KatherineChau and if you wanted to print all of the matches you could replace that printf with for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) print matches[i]; or if you wish to use the printf message and print all matching lines: { printf "CHECK: There are %s lines tied for top:\n\n", cnt; for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) print matches[i] }

Thanks for your help! I had to post a second question on this after I found some issues with my matches. I didn't want to ask it again here as it is technically a new question but it does involve your answer which I accepted as my solution.

grep is not suitable for this job. You may use this awk based solution:
cat srch.awk

BEGIN {FS=","}
FNR == NR {
   if ($1 == s && (!($1 in mx) || mx[$1] < $NF))
      mx[$1] = $NF
   next
}
$1 == s && $NF == mx[$1]

Then use it as:
awk -v s='29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7' -f srch.awk file file
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5

awk -v s='9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9' -f srch.awk file file
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Sphingobacteriia,Sphingobacteriales,???,???,uncultured Cytophagales,2
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma jeollabukense,2
9966f0e6e452c31de46d030bab01fdd9,Bacteria,Bacteroidota,Cytophagia,Cytophagales,Cytophagaceae,Spirosoma,Spirosoma migulaei,2



What is file file supposed to mean here? And for the second awk output I don't want it to return the 3 different lines but rather I was hoping to just return something such as "3 matches found for top!" or something like that....I would need to check those ones out myself.

file file means you need to input file.txt file.txt on command line.

@KatherineChau it means this awk script needs to read the input file twice; FNR==NR / next is used to process the 1st instance of the file while the follow-on code is used to process the 2nd instance of the file

Use awk to match just the lines with the key in the first field. Then test if the value in the last field is equal to or higher than the last maximum found. When it's equal, increment a counter, otherwise reset the counter to 1.
awk -F, -v key=29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7 -v maxval=0 -v count=0 '
    $1 == key { line=$0;
                if ($9 > maxval) { maxval = $9; count = 1; } 
                else if ($9 == maxval) { count++; } }
    END { if (count == 1) { print line }
          else if (count > 1) { printf("CHECK: There are %d lines tied for top.\n", count) }
          else { print "CHECK: Line not found." } '


Here is a Ruby to do that:
$ cat parser.rb
require "csv"
puts "Usage: regexp file" if ARGV.length!=2
tbl=CSV.read(ARGV[1])
header=tbl.shift
asv=header.index("ASV")
hits=header.index("Hits")

regex=Regexp.new(ARGV[0])

if ((matches=tbl.select{|row| row[asv]=~regex}).length)==0 then  
    puts "No matches"
else
    top_n=matches.max_by{|row| row[hits].to_i }[hits]
    match_top=matches.select{|row| row[hits]==top_n}
    
    len=match_top.length
    err="CHECK: There are #{len} lines tied for top."
    
    puts len>1 ? err : match_top[0].to_csv 
end

To run it:
$ ruby parser.rb "^2" file.csv
29ec61e470705074f483368a70ad18a7,Bacteria,???,???,???,???,???,uncultured bacterium,5

$ ruby parser.rb "^9" file.csv
CHECK: There are 3 lines tied for top.

$ ruby parser.rb "^nothing" file.csv
No matches

